# `go tool pprof` reports error `unrecognized profile format`

Tags: go, goroutine, pprof

I am trying to generate PNG of `goroutine` profile with this demo, but it reports error `parsing profile: unrecognized profile format. failed to fetch any source profiles`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime/pprof"
    "time"
)

func main()  {
    // start demo go routine
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    // get executable binary path
    exePath, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    log.Println("exePath", exePath)

    // generate goroutine profile
    profilePath := exePath + ".profile"
    f, err := os.Create(profilePath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    if err := pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(f, 2); err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // generate PNG
    pngPath := exePath + ".png"
    result, err := exec.Command("go", "tool", "pprof", "-png", "-output", pngPath, exePath, profilePath).CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("make error:", err.Error())
    }
    log.Println("make result:", string(result))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a debug value of `2` in `pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(f, 2)`. This will produce an output which the pprof tool can't parse, it is meant as directly human readable.

From the [pprof.(*Profile).WriteTo](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/pprof#Profile.WriteTo) docs:

> The debug parameter enables additional output. Passing debug=0 writes the gzip-compressed protocol buffer described in https://github.com/google/pprof/tree/master/proto#overview. Passing debug=1 writes the legacy text format with comments translating addresses to function names and line numbers, so that a programmer can read the profile without tools.
>
> The predefined profiles may assign meaning to other debug values; for example, when printing the "goroutine" profile, debug=2 means to print the goroutine stacks in the same form that a Go program uses when dying due to an unrecovered panic.

Changing this line to `pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(f, 0)` resolves the issue.

---

Also, not relevant to the issue, but you might want to consider closing the file `f.Close()` before using it in the pprof command. `WriteTo` should flush the file to disk, but it can't hurt.

```golang
if err := pprof.Lookup("goroutine").WriteTo(f, 2); err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Println(err.Error())
    return
}

// generate PNG
...
```